# Identify Short Story/Novel about a boy speeding time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novel

A colleague just gave me a brief description of story/novel but doesn't remember its title but said the author's name sounded french(ish). I am trying to find it:

- The story opens with a boy who can vibrate/oscillate faster than any human and in due course bends time-space. For him the rest of the people seems to stand still like trees and hence couldn't communicate with them in any manner.
- At same time the rest of people (mostly his school mates), search for this boy who they believe disappeared/kidnapped.

It's mostly drama rather than focusing on the sci-fi elements.

Comment: Any idea of age of book? What country was this read in? English language?

Comment: Hello @kaufman. It was read in English, Whereas for the period, I am not sure but I believe its during 19th century.

Comment: If it's really from the 19th century then it beats out H. G. Wells's ["The New Accelerator"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54801) (1901), which I had thought was the first story about speeding up time. Now, the **best** story of that kind is R. A. Lafferty's ["The Six Fingers of Time"](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31663).

Answer (score 2):

A graphic novel with a similar premise:

***Whatever Happened to the World's Fastest Man?***

from Accent UK comics.

Warning: Accent's page for the graphic novel is a major spoiler. I recommend looking for the book elsewhere.